# Anchor links within <ul> stopped working

Tags: html

I just noticed that on several pages - including one of my owns - that some anchor hyperlinks stopped working in Chrome V 61. (Mac or Windows, no difference).  No problems with Safari or FireFox.

i.e. I use it in my header as navigation on a one page layout. It worked fine weeks ago and there were no changes.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

should point to

```
<div class="services" id="service">
```

Standard anchor links - outside of `ul` / `li` are working fine on the same page.

```
<a href="#service" class="line-button">Service</a>
```

points to

```
 <div class="services" id="service">
```

So, what do I miss here?

Comment: They're anchor (not anker) hyperlinks. Can you provide a sample page reproducing the problem (or jsfiddle, etc.)?

Comment: Oh yes, anchor of course, sorry. It's the same in this template here. [link](http://thethemelab.com/envato/Discover/html/) Top Navigation isn't working but all other buttons are. If I put my code in fiddle it's working ...

Comment: And this is why you should always create a minimal example reproducing the problem. One the page you linked, the url doesn't even get updated when clicking navigation links. Disable javascript, and everything works. If you had taken the time to provide us with a jsfiddle reproducing the problem, you would have noticed. Try removing javascript libraries one by one and see when it works or not. Or hosting the scripts on your site, and not through cdns (console warnings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tracked down a solution for the same problem with a wordpress site. The solution came from

```
    https://sridharkatakam.com/fix-jump-links-agency-pro/
```

It is to do with old themes and old versions of jquery.scrollTo.js or jquery.scrollTo.mins.js not working with latest Chrome update.

**Step 1**
Connect to your site’s server via FTP and navigate to theme’s js directory inside the child theme.

**Step 2**
Delete jquery.localScroll.min.js and jquery.scrollTo.min.js.

**Step 3**
Download [jquery.localScroll.min.js](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/raw/master/jquery.localScroll.min.js) and [jquery.scrollTo.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/master/jquery.scrollTo.min.js).

Upload both the files to js directory.

In my case the client did not have a child theme - files are located in wp-content/themes/(your active theme folder)/js
I only needed to replace one file jquery.scrollTo.js - I downloaded the jquery.scrollTo.min.js and renamed it to jquery.scrollTo.js before replacing the old version.

Lots of people are having this issue - took me a few hours to find this solution.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

How you did it, it should work....

The issue is somewhere else, but not in the portion of code you posted ;-)

I think, the issue is in the javascript or CSS. Remove them from the source and try again. If it works now, add it piece by piece to find out, where it happens.

Ideas:

- Anchor itself is missing or malformed
- Some JS routine modifies the a tag or the anchor somewhere before the user clicks so it breaks
- Javascript mousedown/mousemove/mouseup/click event handler calls e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation() or something like this so the click event does not reach the a tag properly.
- A poorly set pointer-events property in your CSS
- It's rare, but possible: A browser bug